# TCL 0 not equal to FALSE

Tags: boolean, tcl

I tried

```
expr 0==false
```

but it returns 0 instead of 1.

According to http://wiki.tcl.tk/16295, False values are the case-insensitive words no, off, false, their unique abbrevations, and 0.

It is weird, or my understanding are wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While specifying operands for `expr` command, to validate against a boolean value, we should use only `string is` command.

```
% expr {0==false}
0
% expr {[string is false 0]}
1
```

Simply validating against boolean equal `==` will treat them as if like literal string/list.

**Reference :** [expr](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm#M5)

Comment: I% expr {[string is true 2]} 
0
% expr {[string is false -1]}
0

Comment: @Tai Huynh Phuoc :  `string is` command with `true` or `false` accepts any value which are in the form of `Tcl_GetBoolean`. It expects the source to specify a `boolean` value. If source is any of `0`, `false`, `no`, or `off`, then `Tcl_GetBoolean` stores a zero value at `*boolPtr`. If source is any of `1`, `true`, `yes`, or `on`, then 1 is stored at `*boolPtr`. Any of these values may be abbreviated, and upper-case spellings are also acceptable. i.e. It supports only the mentioned values. Rest will always return `0` only.

Comment: This is why you are getting `[string is true 2]` or `[string is false -1]` as `0`

Comment: Be aware that both `[string is true $var]` and `[string is false $var]` would return "1" if $var contained an empty string. To make sure that the value must not be empty, use `[string is true -strict $var]`.